# Git hooks for executing mocha-tests before commit or merge

Tags: git, makefile, phantomjs, mocha.js, githooks

I'm not quite sure, if this can be done with git hooks - that's why I split this question into three parts:

1. First do a test (mocha/phantomjs/meteor). If it passes, a commit can be done

For that I tried something like this:

**hooks/pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/bash
// First check if current branch is 'development'
meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --mocha --path=tests --browser=phantomjs
```

So what I would expect is, that the tests are executed first. If any test fails, no commit will be done, if all passes, the commit will be executed.
As you see, I'm not very familiar with bash-scripts (I'm using MacOS). That's why I need you help to get this simple script working.

The Mocha docs (https://mochajs.org/) say there is a 'proper exit status for CI support'. So if I understand this correctly it will do a `exit 1` if any test fails.

2. Just do tests if merging from `development` to `master` branch

As the tests take some minutes, I'm thinking of it would be a bit smarter if they will only be run, before the development branch gets merged into the master branch. 
So on master branch there is alwys just tested code. But how do I get the info which branch is the current one? And also I just found the info, that there is only a `post-merge`, but no `pre-merge` hook.

3. Do a `Makefile` deploy after merging

After successful merging I would like to execute `make` to do the deploy to the server. Therefore I would use the `post-merge`-hook.

**hooks/post-merge**

```
#!/bin/bash
// be sure we are in 'master' branch
make
```

But how do I know if the merge was successful (or will this be checked by git?) and how do I execute the makefile correctly?

So basically I'm struggling with the correct bash scripts...

Answer (score 1):

Mocha does exit with an error, but your commit-hook doesn't.

> mocha test/mocha/ --recursive -b || exit 1

did the trick for me.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more?